# Weird partial mesh collapsing inwards after switching from sculpting mode? (Bug?)

Tags: sculpting

I got Blender yesterday for sculpting, today i tried working on the hair of this face i worked on. It went well until i switched to shading and layout mode. I honestly don't know how to properly describe this so i couldn't find any bug reports that were similar.

Does anyone know what causes it, how to avoid it in the future and how to fix it?

This is what it looks like:
[image]

Even though it looks fine in sculpt mode:
[image]

Here some screenshots of the shapekeys (I think?) :
[image]
[image]

On that note, the wireframe view seems a little off as well:
[image]
Sorry if this has been asked before, couldn't find the right wording for it.

Comment: Hello and welcome. If there is a material on the object, i'd recommend to remove it to see if that fixes the problem. Sadly there is not much visible beside the effect/problem, so adding a screen shot of the shader and/or possible shape keys could help discern more. You can use [edit](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/181841/edit) to add more details to your question. **If you don't mind**, you can always use the [Blend-Exchange](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com) to share your file for a hands-on checkup possibility.

Comment: Hello and thank you for answering! I'm completely new to blender and a bit lost at the moment, but I'll try my best to add the relevant info to the question.

Comment: Sorry, this is only a comment, as i can not yet with certainty answer, thus i have to dig a bit. Seeing that there is actually a shape-key, i wonder if you select the key and change the value, would the collapsed part be corrected. The last image though is like that because you have the x-ray and wireframe on. Sadly problems with scenes in Blender usually can have dozens of different reasons and while some situations can be made out by key factors, this has me guessing. To be **able** to check deeper, i would remind about the file-sharing option, since you did not directly rejected it.